# Navegacion entre Vistas Swiftui,como resolver acumulacion de vistas

Tags: swift, login, navigationview, views

Hola buenas quiero realizar el loguin con **Apple** en **Swiftui**,mi codigo lo hace pero necesito que si o si me muestre el mail, por ende si el usuario pone hide (ocultar), se tiene que loguiar nuevamente. Lo que pasa que al volver a la pantalla de loguin, se me van acumulando las vistas, ya que no me deja ocultar la vista con la informacion de quien se loguio, no me funciona el @Environment(.presentationMode) var presentation, ya que todo se crea en el ContentView y las vistas se colocan en la misma pantalla, no aparte.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var name = ""
@State var email = ""

@EnvironmentObject var authorizationStatus: UserSettings

var body: some View {
    NavigationView{
        
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: nil){
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: nil) {
                if self.name.isEmpty && UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "nombre") == nil {
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: nil, content: {
                        SignUpWithAppleView(name: $name, email: $email)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 50)
                    })
                }
                else{
                    NuevaVista()
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

struct NuevaVista: View {

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

let nombre = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "nombre") as! String
let mail = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email") as! String
@Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentation

@State private var showlink = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: nil){
            if mail == "sin mail"{
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing:nil){
                    Text("Debe compartir su Email \n para usar esta APP \n vuelva a loguearse")
                        .font(.title)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Button(action:{
                        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "nombre")
                        self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                        self.showlink = true
                    }){
                        Text("OK")
                        
                    }
                    .background(NavigationLink("",
                                    destination: ContentView(),
                                    isActive: $showlink),alignment: .center)
                }     
            }
```

Comment: Al presionar el botón no haces `NavigationLink` a otra vista? Todo trabajas en la vista `ContentView`

Comment: Claro esta en el mismo content, porque ya se genera el boton en el codigo de la vista. Pero si quiere volver a iniciar sesion no carga de nuevo el contentview, nose como hacer que se refresque esa vista.

Answer (score 0):

Debes quitar el `.background` en la estructura `NuevaVista`, funciona bien con la línea:

```
self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

El código lo tengo así:

```
if mail == "sin mail"{
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing:nil){
        Text("Debe compartir su Email \n para usar esta APP \n vuelva a loguearse")
        .font(.title)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        
        Button(action: {
                            UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "nombre")
                            self.presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            self.showlink = true
                        }) {
                            Text("OK")
                        }
                    }
    }
}
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero el apple button como lo tenes programado?, solo abre la pantalla? Porque lo que me sucede ami es que hace un login ,y luego verifica si dejo tildado que muestra el mail o si lo oculta, y en este caso si lo oculta debe ingresar a login de nuevo.

Answer (score 0):

Regularmente solo debes tener un `NavigationView` deja la de `ContentView` y remueve las otras.

Hay pocas excepciones como `.sheet`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).